# How can I Display Text Files?

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I have a program that allows the user to complete test where all the user's scores are recorded in a seperate text file for each test. How would I display each text file so that for each test the scores can be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Linq query:

```
var scores = from file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\path", "*.scores")
             select GetScoreFromFile(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file));
```

with `GetScoreFromFile`:

```
private int GetScoreFromFile(string[] scoreLines)
{
    // Some code to read the score from the file
}
```

To actually display the scores... You probably want to make something fancy (it sounds pretty game-like). If not, go with some sort of `Grid` control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ini configuration file to do this. I have designed a VB class library which contains an ini File reader class which can be used to read and write to ini configuration files. Rather than save each score as a separate file, you can contain it in a single ini configuration file by separating them in sections.

You can download my class library [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?gcyx68tc1i4ca2x)

Add a reference to the library in your project.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
Dim ScoresReader As New Rodit.IniLib.IniParser

Public Sub ReadTestScores(ScoreFilePath As String)
    ScoresReader = New Rodit.IniLib.IniParser 'Initializes new instance of class
    ScoresReader.Load(ScoreFilePath) 'Loads scores file specified in subroutine args
    For Each score As Rodit.IniLib.IniParser.IniSection In ScoresReader.Sections 'Each section in the ini file will represent a different user's score
        'Here you can write whatever you want to do with the user's score
    Next
End Sub

'Call example:
Protected Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ReadTestScores("C:\scores.ini")
End Sub
```

Ini file stucture:

```
[INIFILETEST] <-- Section
Name=Rodit
 ^     ^
 |     |
Key   Value
```

By understanding this, it would be easy to read and write your scores using this method...

Hope this helped...

Rodit